# Finding an average value using integer arrays

Tags: arrays, vb.net, list, numbers, integer

In my program I have designed it so that it reads from a file, parses the file for any integers and saves them to a sorted list. From that list I have then created three arrays which would each hold different values based off the values in the list except the values would go up by 1 for each array so:

Example Values:

```
array 1 will hold the regular values e.g. - 2,3,4,5
array 2 will hold the regular values (+1) - 3,4,5,6
array 3 will hold the regular values (+2) - 4,5,6,7

2,3,4 = 1st user's score
3,4,5 = 2nd user's score
4,5,6 = 3rd user's score
```

From this I now want to add these arrays together and divide by 3 to get the average results and then save and join the values with their corresponding user, however am not sure if I can add the arrays directly.

This is the code I have so far:

```
Dim basenum As New System.Collections.Generic.List(Of Integer)
Dim num As String
num = Regex.Replace(line, "\D+", "")
For Each lin As String In num
    basenum.Add(Convert.ToInt32(lin))
Next
basenum.Sort()
basenum.Reverse()
For Each element As Integer In basenum
    Console.WriteLine(element)
Next
Dim number1() As Integer
Dim number2() As Integer
Dim number3() As Integer
number1 = basenum.ToArray
For Each element As Integer In number1
    Console.WriteLine(element)
Next
number2 = basenum.ToArray 'insert 2nd numbers into second array
For Each element As Integer In number2
    element += 1
    Console.WriteLine(element)
Next
number3 = basenum.ToArray 'insert 3rd numbers into third array
For Each element As Integer In number3
    element += 2
    Console.WriteLine(element)
Next
```

The numbers go into the arrays fine however am not sure how I can add the arrays together and calculate the average.

Any help would be appreciated guys :)

Comment: please explain what `regular values (+1) - 3` means.  `Dim avg = number1.Average` may be all you need

Comment: Plutonix it isn't part of the program, it is just how the values in the array will add up.

Comment: Well you are trying to tell us something about something by including it.  I dont see where a "score of 2" comes about from what follows.  Summing 3 arrays and dividing by 3 doesnt give you an average of the array values.  *What* you are trying to do is unclear

Comment: Re Edit: Those sum to 14, 18, 22 - how does that result in a score of 2?

Comment: I want to increase the values by 1 when they go up in each array and add them at the end, so if a user got 2 then that would be stored in the first array and it would go up by 1 for the two other arrays so the second array would have 3 and the third would have 4. I then want to add these values (2 + 3 + 4) and divide by three to get the average. would that work?

Comment: So you dont like the code you have to do that?  Whats that got to do with averaging?  Is this 2 questions in one?

Comment: Yeah, pretty much i need to know if i can calculate the average by adding each of the values in the arrays (2"array1"+3"array2"+4"array3") and then divide by 3 and if not how I could calculate the average for each user

Comment: There is a difference between average score (all values / count of values) and average user score (sum each user then divide).  Why are there now 4 values in the arrays but you only refer to the first three (and leaves out the highest).  Yes it can be done

Comment: the values in the arrays depend on what score the user got (read from a text file) so it will vary, so the numbers used at the top of the page are just examples of what could happen in the program. And i think i forgot to write out the fourth user's score. Nonetheless i do want to work out the average score of each user.

Comment: Ok.  You are all over the board with this.  `Number1.Avg` will give you the avg of that array.  `Number1.Take(3).Avg` will average just the first 3.  `Number1.Sum` will return the sum of that array which was important in earlier editions...and `avgUserScore = (number1.Take(3).Sum + number2.Take(3).Sum + number3.Take(3).Sum) / 9`  9 could be replaced by `number1.Count -1 + ...`

Comment: Use 1 array. Calculate the average using this formula: ((number*3)+3)/3. Or the average will always be +1 from your value